# How to use the free space after narrow /home partition in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I want to install windows7 with my current system ubuntu,and the first step I should do is to allocate a partition for win7.So I decided to narrow my /home patition.Therefore,I execute the following command line

```
umount /home
e2fsck -f /dev/sda3
resize2fs -p /dev/sda3 150G
mount /dev/sda3 /home
```

It worked.
And then I viewed the information by df -lh

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           384M  1.3M  383M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        23G   12G   11G  53% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  164K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda3       148G   87G   54G  62% /home
```

But I don't know how to do next.How can I make use of the free space?

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and/or a GParted screenshot.

Comment: Note also that (as indicated on its mnaual page) `resize2fs` only resizes the filesystem and not the partition. Why not just use GParted?

Comment: Thanks for you advice.I have solved the problem according to your advice.But the new problem occurred.I tried to use grub to guide the installation of win7.But We I use`sudo apt-get install grub`,it shows `grub : Conflicts: grub-efi-amd64 Conflicts: grub-efi-amd64:i386`.How should I do to solve the problem.

Comment: @dapao This Grub problem should be asked in a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted is a great tool for partitioning your HDD/SSD. Get it here:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Here you can change the format of the free space.